# Hypothetically, could the interior of a black hole look exactly like the universe that surrounds us?

Tags: cosmology, black-holes, space-expansion, event-horizon, singularities

I do understand that we can't experimentally verify anything we imagine about the interior of a black hole.

If we were to apply what we know about the physics of the observable universe and assume that those laws remain valid on the other side of an event horizon, then are the following assumptions at least plausible?

- Anything that falls into a black hole *might* experience perpetual free-fall, because everything closer to the singularity will experience a much stronger pull than things farther away.
- The observer, similarly, will experience a constant acceleration away from the event horizon, so objects that cross it after the observer does will always be moving away from them, from their point of view.
- Objects within the event horizon of a black hole can't interact with *our* observable universe, but there doesn't (to me) seem to be any reason why they can't interact with each other.  So they could clump together in volumes that are small enough where the tidal forces don't rip them apart.
- In this way, wouldn't the inside of a black hole look like a universe where everything is constantly accelerating away from each other, but in smaller scales can still bind together through all the normal interactions that we observe on "this side"?

I hope this question doesn't break the rules of stackexchange, and I'm totally ready to have all of the above bullet points torn to shreds.

Comment: The inner space of a black hole is not isotropic. An inner Schwarzschild timeslice is a spherinder (http://hi.gher.space/wiki/Spherinder) or roughly speaking a shrinking cylinder. According to the current cosmology, the universe is the expanding isotropic FLRW space. Not the same. However, the inner space of the Oppenheimer-Snyder white hole also is the expanding FLRW space. So the universe being an Oppenheimer-Snyder white hole (not black hole) is consistent with the current cosmology. There is no evidence to disprove this (without also disproving the “official” current cosmology).

Comment: “*because everything closer to the singularity will experience a much stronger pull*” - This is incorrect. A singularity is not an object in space in the present, but a future moment of time that cannot “pull” anything in the present. A singularity does not exist in the space of a falling observer until his last moment. A “pull” normally means “gravitational acceleration” that you can conceptually stop by rocket engines. Inside a black hole you simply are moving in time. No engines can stop your movement towards tomorrow inside or outside a black hole.